# Insert into different tables of db according to option selected in dropdown list using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 4 different table. e.g. flags,scenarios,injectors,languages. i want a page with name and dropdown option in php. so, according to the selected dropdown option the name should be inserted to the associate table in db. eg. if i give any name xyz and select flag option. then the name sholud be inserted in flag table.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"])) {    
    $name = $_REQUEST["name"];
    $option = $_REQUEST["option"];

    if($option = "flags")
    {
        mysql_query("insert into flags(name)values('$name')"); 
    }

    if($option="languages")
    {
        mysql_query("insert into languages(name)values('$name')"); 
    }

    if($option="injectors")
    {
        mysql_query("insert into injectors(name)values('$name')"); 
    }

    if($option="scenarios")
    {
        mysql_query("insert into scenarios(name)values('$name')"); 
    } 
}

echo'
    <form method="post"> 
        Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
        Options:
        <select>
            <option value="flags" >flags</option>
            <option value="scenarios" >scenarios</option>
            <option value="languages" >languages</option>
            <option value="injectors" >injectors</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="insert" name="create"></input>
    </form>';
```

Comment: Okay... but you forgot to ask a (specific) question... if you want the code you have to write it on your own...

Comment: `but you forgot to ask a (specific) question` LOL :-)

Comment: The `mysql_*` extension is obsolete and insecure - please don't use it in new code.

Comment: You are also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: `$_REQUEST["option"]` for that to work your `<select>` tag would need `name="option"`

Comment: `if($option="flags")` < `=` there is an [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) not a [comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php); you make that mistake throughout your code, it should be `==` or `===` depending on how strict you want to be.

Comment: `if(isset($_REQUEST["submit"]))` ... `$_REQUEST['submit']` will never be set from this code, your input button is called *"create"* : `<input type="submit" ... name="create">`

Comment: thank you...i made so many mistakes...its working now. i changed = to == and 'create' to submit.